# Python - Loop through each row of multiple dataframes in a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dataframe

I am trying to export each tweet that I incorrectly classify.

I am using the below code (taken online and adjusted), which uses a confusion matrix to determine what tweets I have been incorrectly classified:

```
misclassified_svm = []
misclassified_svm_details = []

for predicted in event_id_df.event_id:
    for actual in event_id_df.event_id:
        if predicted != actual and conf_mat_svm[actual, predicted] >= 3:
            misclassified_svm.append("'{}' predicted as '{}' : {} examples.".format(id_to_event[actual], id_to_event[predicted], 
                  conf_mat_svm[actual,predicted]))
            misclassified_svm_details.append(testing_data_svm.loc[testing_data_svm.index[(testing_data_svm.actual_event_id == actual)& (testing_data_svm.predicted_event_id == predicted)]][['actual_event_type', 'preprocessed']])
```

This populates the list *misclassified_svm* with an overview of what has been incorrectly misclassified. This can be seen below:

[image: Overview of misclassified tweets]

The intention was to populate the list *misclassified_svm_details* with each of the misclassified tweets, so I can understand features causing the misclassification. Instead, it creates a list of dataframes. This can be seen below:

[image: Screenshot of variables and dataframes contained within a list]

I would like the end result to be a variable that I can export, which contains every row of every dataframe within the list *miclassified_svm_details*.

To be clear, I will be running this code with different datasets, so I need the proposed solution to be flexible and adapt to their being a different number of dataframes in the list and a different number of entries in each dataframe.

Just for completeness, here is my failed attempt:

```
misclassified_svm_det_2 = []

for a in misclassified_svm_details:
   for b in range(len(misclassified_svm_details)):
        misclassified_svm_det_2.append(b)
```

This simply creates a list of 36 entries, which cycles through 0-5 six times.

Comment: can you create a minimal reproducible example showing the input and the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than appending Dataframes to a list you could just make  misclassigied_svm_details` a DataFrame from the start and append each dataset you produce to it.

So your code would read:

```
misclassified_svm = []
misclassified_svm_details = pd.DataFrame(columns=['actual_event_type', 'preprocessed'])

for predicted in event_id_df.event_id:
    for actual in event_id_df.event_id:
        if predicted != actual and conf_mat_svm[actual, predicted] >= 3:
            misclassified_svm.append("'{}' predicted as '{}' : {} examples.".format(id_to_event[actual], id_to_event[predicted], 
                  conf_mat_svm[actual,predicted]))
            misclassified_svm_details.append(testing_data_svm.loc[testing_data_svm.index[(testing_data_svm.actual_event_id == actual)& (testing_data_svm.predicted_event_id == predicted)]][['actual_event_type', 'preprocessed']])
```